# How to properly structure an object with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I am in the learning process of learning better JavaScript. Right now, I am  trying to make an object, for just handling strings. Just for the fun of learning.

I have tried to google around, for the correct way, or preferred way of doing this, but cannot seem to find a good, trusty tutorial on how to initiate objects.

I tried something similar to this:

```
(function(StringHelper, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    StringHelper.isString = function() {
        // Do stuff
    };

    StringHelper.toLowercase = function() {
        // Do stuff
    };

    StringHelper.toUppercase = function() {
        // Do stuff
    };
}());

}(window.StringHelper = window.StringHelper || {}));

();
```

I got this from https://codepen.io/grav-sebastian/pen/ZpvxYJ, I am not sure what it really means (the way of doing it), like what does the last part `window.StringHelper = window.StringHelper || do`?

Is this a good way of structuring simple JavaScript? Is it reusable for others and myself in a good way?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't even valid JavaScript.  There's an unexpected `}` character on the second to last line...

Answer (score 3):

Your question is pretty opened. There is not a canonical way to instantiate javaScript objects, like in other languages where the only way to create an object is to create a constructor.

Essentially, you can either use a constructor function, using the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), or return an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). However, even if these are -AFAIK- the only two ways to directly create objects at a fundamental level, there are several strategies to create objects, like [factory functions](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e#.f00seg4if) and [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). A lot of strategies rely on creating just empty objects and then decorate them adding functions and properties.

While most of the standard browser and node API's exposes constructors, there are a lot of developers who think constructors in javaScript -and, implicitly, the `this` keyword- are evil (just google 'javascript new harmful').

Regarding the code you pasted, as @Mayank said, all that code is about creating a new object in case `window.StringHelper` is not yet defined, or defining some functions for it in case it yet exists. However is pretty convoluted and is not the most straightforward way to deal with object creation at all.

So, a standard, constructor way to create an object would be:

```
var Dancer = function(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Dancer.prototype.greet = function(){
    return 'Hi! I\'m ' + this.name;
}
```

And a way to do it through a closure -which allows privacy- would be:

```
function createDancer(name){
    var module = {};

    module.greet = function(){
        return 'Hi! I\'m ' + name;
    };
    return module;
}
```

However, there are really many strategies in javaScript to handle object creation, everyone with its own advantages and caveats.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfMtDGfHWpA) explains a simple yet powerful pattern to create object and reuse them avoiding the common pitfall of the `new` and `this` keywords in javaScript.

Other interesting resource about object creation in javaScript is the [stampit framework](https://github.com/stampit-org/stampit).

Answer (score 0):

window.StringHelper = window.StringHelper || {} is used as a namespace which means if window.StringHelper is already declared, then it won't redeclare (the || {} part) otherwise it will declare window.StringHelper (window.StringHelper || part) as a namespace.

For learning better javascript [this](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) is a good resource.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok, that makes good sense. Is this way of writing an object a good way? 

What does the top do? "(function(StringHelper, undefined) {" ? In the original code there was also a $ and JQuery at the bottom, I assumed that was for jQuery support?